# adding total intval version of numbers in string

Tags: php, string, integer

Did something change in a recent version of PHP ? Or was it always like this ?

```
$totalAmount = 0;

foreach ($this->_data['investments'] as $investment)
{
    // Remove commas and convert the "Amount" value to an integer
    $amount = intval(str_replace(',', '', $investment['Amount']));

    // Add the integer "Amount" to the total
    $totalAmount += $amount;
}

echo "totalAmount = ";
```

`die($totalAmount);` echos empty string

where as

`die($totalAmount."")` echos the amount in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is consistent with how PHP has generally worked. The `die()` function in PHP is an alias for `exit()`, which outputs a message and terminates the script. When you pass an integer to `die()`, it is treated as an exit status code, not as output to display. Exit status codes are usually not displayed in the browser or console; they are meant for the operating system or calling program to interpret.

In the first example:

```
die($totalAmount);
```

You're passing an integer to `die()`, so it's treated as an exit status code, not as output to display.

In the second example:

```
die($totalAmount."");
```

You're concatenating an empty string to `$totalAmount`, which effectively converts the integer to a string. When `die()` receives a string, it outputs that string before terminating the script.

To make sure you're outputting the value you expect, you can either cast the integer to a string as you've done in the second example, or you can use echo before calling `die()` or `exit()`:

```
echo "totalAmount = " . $totalAmount;
die();
```

This will display the value of `$totalAmount` and then terminate the script.

Comment: Oh thanks - I totally mistook PHP's die() for something different from python's `sys.exit()`